# WooCommerce Product Feeds Google merchant center

Tags: woocommerce, feed

I have been trying to extract useful product feeds but there is still one attribute missing in the feed "image link"
Can anyone suggest me a tweak in the following query to make it perfect?

```
SELECT
    `product`.`ID` AS `product_id`,
    `product`.`post_title` AS `Title`,
    `product`.`post_title` AS `Description`,
    `product_price`.`meta_value` AS `Price`,
    'no' AS `Identifier_exists`,
    'Free' AS `Shipping`,
    'in stock' AS `Availability`,
    'new' AS `Condition`,
    `product`.`guid` AS `Link`
FROM
    (
        (
            (
                `wp_posts` `product`
            LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` `product_sku`
            ON
                (
                    (
                        `product`.`ID` = `product_sku`.`post_id`
                    )
                )
            )
        LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` `product_price`
        ON
            (
                (
                    `product`.`ID` = `product_price`.`post_id`
                )
            )
        )
    LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` `product_weight`
    ON
        (
            (
                `product`.`ID` = `product_weight`.`post_id`
            )
        )
    )
WHERE
    (
        (
            (`product`.`post_type` = 'product') 
          OR(`product`.`post_type` = 'product_variation')

        ) AND(`product_sku`.`meta_key` = '_sku') AND(
            `product_price`.`meta_key` = '_price'
        ) AND(
            `product_weight`.`meta_key` = '_weight'
        )
    )
ORDER BY
    `product_id`
```

Comment: Have you tried this free [woocommerce product feed](https://wordpress.org/plugins/webtoffee-product-feed/) plugin

Comment: Yes I tried but it fails because the feed.csv size exceeds over 250 MBs means the total number of products and variations is beyond its capability.

Comment: How are you going to manage the query output to upload to the Google merchant center.? Above mentioned plugin has the option to uncheck unwanted columns, which can reduce the size a little bit.